# Get hours out of TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We are using TFS for source control and to track tasks. How can I get the hours that we put against tasks out of TFS? Specifically, I'd like to be able to see when the hours were put on the task, but I'd settle to just see the hours per task.

Update:
This is what I can get if I use SSAS

[image: TFS Hours]

However, I know not all of those days I put in a complete hour, so that's not 100% accurate.

Comment: What do you mean, "get the hours"? The hours are a field on the task work item.

Comment: @John Saunders by "Get the hours" I mean I would like to see them in a report by person by date.

Comment: GIGO: there is no magical tracking of actual time spent. Any tracking will depend on actual data placed into TFS. If you enter 1 hour, then that's what will be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to retrieve the hours that correspond to the WI-fields? --> In this case you can proceed as @kroonwijk suggests, you can also do this via TFS-API.

In case you are looking to apply a time-tracking utility on TFS, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487254/tfs-time-tracking-and-bug-tracking) out - there are apparently various options available. An additional option might also be [this](http://www.imaginet.com/Solutions/ALM/Pages/Notion-Timesheet.aspx) one.

Comment: Yes.  I'd like to see when myself or others change the completed hours value.  Say on monday i did 2.5 hours worth of work on different tasks and then did 3 hours worth of tasks on tuesday.  I'd like to be able to se 2.5 hours for monday and 3 for tuesday.

Comment: Let's say you have an assigned TFS Task, on which you work 2.5 hours on Monday & 3 hours on Tuesday. If you have entered these hours on the Completed Hours field of the Task (ontime!) you can proceed as @kroonwijk suggests. If you haven't, you need to employ a time-traking entity in your landscape, so you 'll be able to get your reports in the future

Answer (score 2):

Connect your Excel application to the TFS2010 analysis cube and you will be able to get the hours administered to a task and even the date and time that these hours have been administered.

See http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/02/22/tfs-reporting-with-excel-1.aspx on how to connect Excel 2007 / 2010 to the TFS2010 analysis cube.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party solution for time tracking: http://www.imaginet.com/Solutions/ALM/Pages/Notion-Timesheet.aspx. The problem with reporting hours in the Work Items is that you cannot specify a date on which the hours apply. With the time sheet you are able to bind hours to a work item and a day.

I have created a report in the past that tries to pull the hours out of the TFS system: http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2009/07/09/Time-Entry-report.aspx

Comment: i couldn't get the report to open in vs 2005

Comment: Do you have BIDS installed (install sql server 2005 on your machine and choose to install it)

Comment: Yes I do have bids installed.  When I get a chance i'll provide you the error I got.